# VSCode mouse-hover on Python Keywords not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

While beginning to teach a friend how to code in Python, I observed something in his VSCode that was different than my own - he could mouse-hover on a Python keyword such as as `import` or `def`, and it would show the Python Manual definition for the keyword. My own VSCode does not do this.

I have tried everything I can think of to find why this won't work for me, and I'm at a complete loss. I have compared my installation process to my friend's, followed the exact same steps I provided him for setting up his environment, and do not get the same results. I tried completely removing Python, VSCode and all residual VSCode files from my laptop, and reinstalling in the same order he did, still to no avail.

I followed those same steps on a different laptop at work, and I can get the MouseHover to work there. The only feasible difference I can think of is that my work machine is not using the same Windows account as both my home PC and laptop - but I do not have Settings Sync enabled so I can't see why that should matter anyway.

Any thoughts for what I'm overlooking to get this functionality working properly in VSCode for myself? I don't particularly need it, but I'd like to be in the same environment as my friend while I teach him.

We're both on VSCode 1.55.2, Python 3.9.4, using a virtual environment created from VSCode's Powershell terminal, then restarted VSCode to get it to detect the virtual environment and use it as default for Terminals, and finally pip installed and enabled Pylint as the linter.

Editing to add steps followed - I just went through all of this again on my home laptop, after completely removing all traces of VisualStudio2019 and Code, and Python. Note: this was on Windows 10, with all updates applied

- Install VSCode
- Install VSCode Python extension, MS version
- Install Python 3.9.4
- Open a new folder in VSCode, then open Terminal
- python -m venv venv
- create a `something.py` in the Explorer pane
- VSCode should detect the venv and offer to load it. Say yes
- VScode may also indiacte that `pylint` is not installed, Allow it to install, or manually `pip install pylint` from the venv.
- in `something.py` type out `import random`
- Mouse over `import` -- this is the discrepancy. On both of my home machines, there is no mousehover anything. on both of my friend's machines, as well as my machine at work, the following is shown:

[image: MouseHover on keywords]

Comment: I only have the ms-python extension and do not have this feature (Python 3.8). He must have installed an additional extension. I don't see a difference for the 2 Language Servers (PyLance and Microsoft)

Comment: Pylance isn't involved - and he has only the two extensions installed, ms-python, and the jupyter notebooks extension it forces.

Comment: I should add that the MouseHover on things like class and variable name DOES work properly.

Comment: @Rayanth -Could you please provide us with a concrete example that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Part of why I'm asking is to figure out what could be different - i don't know how to reproduce it when of the 5 machines we performed this on, 3 worked and 2 didn't. I will edit the OP to add the steps we followed.

Comment: The pylint question should happen if pylint is enabled, the user HAS to enable pylint in VSC, where did this setting change? Could it be that some of the computers are part of the Python Experiments of the language server. Look in the `OUTPUT : Python` panel at the top.

Comment: @riov8 interesting, i did not even know of that panel, and had to look around for it. I seem to belong to 9 different python experiment groups. I will have to wait until this evening to see if my friend is a member of any/the same ones, and will check when i get to work for that machine as well. Is there some way to remove myself from these experiment groups? or to report bugs related to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from riov8's comment on the original post, I was able to compare the Experiment Groups that were in effect for each of the environments.

- In VSCode, with a Python file loaded, switch to the Output panel (in same area as Terminal) and change the dropdown to Python.
- Scroll to the top of this panel, and examine the Experiment Groups you belong to.
- Most of the experiment groups do not apply to this issue.
- Look specifically for either `pythonJediLSP`, `pythonJediLSPcf` or if
  you have neither.

If you are experiencing the issue I describe, then at the bottom of this same panel, when you first mouse over a python **keyword** after starting VSCode, you will get errors similar to the following:

```
Error 2021-04-16 15:33:40: stderr jediProxy Error (stderr) %UserProfile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\completion.py:598: DeprecationWarning: Providing the line is now done in the functions themselves like `Script(...).complete(line, column)`
  sys_path=sys.path,
%UserProfile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\completion.py:598: DeprecationWarning: Providing the column is now done in the functions themselves like `Script(...).complete(line, column)`
  sys_path=sys.path,

Error 2021-04-16 15:33:40: stderr jediProxy Error (stderr) %UserProfile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\completion.py:598: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated since version 0.17.0. Use the project API instead, which means Script(project=Project(dir, sys_path=sys_path)) instead.
  sys_path=sys.path,

Error 2021-04-16 15:33:40: stderr jediProxy Error (stderr) %UserProfile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\completion.py:626: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated since version 0.16.0. Use Script(...).infer instead.
  script.goto_definitions(), request["id"]
```

The following scenarios resolved the issue for me:

### User belongs to experiment group `pythonJediLSPcf`:

- File > Preferences > Settings
- in Search Settings, begin typing `python.experiment`
- under Python> Experiments: Opt Out From, click `Edit in settings.json`
- in the section `"python.experiments.optOutFrom"`, add `"pythonJediLSPcf"` (quoted)
- if it does not exist, add another section `"python.experiments.optInto"`
- In the OptInto section, add `"pythonJediLSP"` (quoted)
- Save the settings.json, and restart VSCode.
- MouseHover tooltips on Python keywords now should work.

### User does not belong to either `pythonJediLSPcf` or `pythonJediLSP`:

- File > Preferences > Settings
- in Search Settings, begin typing `python.experiment`
- under Python › Experiments: Opt Into, click `Edit in settings.json`
- In the `"python.experiments.optInto` section, add `"pythonJediLSP"` (quoted)
- Save the settings.json, and restart VSCode.
- MouseHover tooltips on Python keywords now should work.

### User belongs to `pythonJediLSP`:

- It was my experience that this was the experiment required in order for the feature to work properly. If you have this experiment enabled already, then ensure you do not also have `pythonJediLSPcf`. Disable it if you do, following the instructions in the first sub-heading. If it continues to not work, then there may be another conflict that I did not experience myself.

I am posting a GitHub issue regarding this problem and will update this answer with the link when done.